# Fix a header on the top relative to a div container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am having problem fixing the header on top. The header is inside a container div and i want it to stay on the top even if the container div is scrolled.

HTML :

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="fixed">
            SHOULD BE FIXED
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
.wrapper{
    width:300px;
    height:200px;
    margin:auto;
    border:1px solid #ddd;
    overflow-y:scroll;
    overflow-x:hidden;
}
.container{
    width:300px;
    position:relative;
    height:1000px;
    background:#111;
}
.fixed{
    background:#aaa;
    position:absolute;
    height:50px;
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:15px 0;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Here is a **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/F2Fhd/1/)**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Style `position: fixed` is the way to go:

```
.fixed {
    position: fixed;
    width: inherit;
}
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/F2Fhd/3/

Comment: Just add some content before or after and it break http://jsfiddle.net/aamir/K9jaz/1/

Comment: This solves the problem. I didn't know about `width: inherit` and  i was trying `width:100%` which was causing the fixed div to expand to the browser's width. Thanks btw :)

Comment: @AamirAfridi Why also not to change the width of the container to `30000px`? Your case is a completely different question with different circumstances.

Comment: One thing I would like to ask. If my outer div is also set to 100% and I have defined the width to a div multiple levels above, then what would solve it?

Comment: @DanglingCruze `inherit` will set the property value exactly the same as in its parent element. So if the parent container will have width 100%, the child with `width: inherit` will automatically get width 100%. You need to test if that works on your example, otherwise, (most probably) you will need to use some JavaScript.

Comment: Hardcoding width solves the problem. But I'm not sure of the width.

Comment: @DanglingCruze than your simplest way to do it is with a couple of lines of JS to get the desired element innerWidth and set accordingly the fixed elemetn width.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Awesome name! However the code behind is not much sexy `:D`

Comment: @VisioN the code behind is sexy as setting 300px width to an `overflow-y:scroll` element :D

Comment: I was thinking of using JS and would go that way if this is not going to happen with CSS. Because I don't want the style to be scattered until JS loads and does it job.

Comment: @VisioN did you get my problem?

Comment: @DanglingCruze Yes, I did get. I see no other solutions except injecting some JS to the markup.

Comment: @DanglingCruze you'll **have** to use JS cause as soon you set an element to `fixed` it becomes literally a *poo* not worth touching but with a stick (JavaStick :D ), Cause they had not yet invented some more dynamic CSS calculations like `calc(inherit - 17px);`

Comment: Haha.. then i must use JS! Thanks for your responses.

Answer (score 0):

Change in .fixed class postion:absolute for postion:fixed and set width to 300px! :)

CSS:

```
.fixed{
    background:#aaa;
    position:fixed;
    height:50px;
    width:300px;
    text-align:center;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:15px 0;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/F2Fhd/4/

Comment: Actually, here I had to specify the width, but I'm using 100% in my setup which is causing the fixed div to fit the browsers width. How to limit that?

Comment: so try width: inherit;

Answer (score -1):

try using jquery for a more crossbrowser friendlier way.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
var div = $('**.fixed**');
var start = $(div).offset().top;
$.event.add(window, "scroll", function() {
    var ul = $(window).scrollTop();
    $(div).css('position',((ul)>start) ? 'fixed' : '');
});
});
$('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') 
    || location.hostname == this.hostname) {

    var target = $(this.hash);
    target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
       if (target.length) {
         $('html,body').animate({
             scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 2000);
        return false;
    }
}
});
</script>
```

Comment: roko, position: fixed is not comptable in all browsers using css.  this fixed header he is asking for is a better way to go than using css.